# Checking characters of a string using boolean method of the same class

Tags: java, string, for-loop, char, boolean

This is one programming task i'm working toward to. I'm currently struggling with the main method of the code. Supposedly, what i am trying to do is to use the isDNASequence method to check the individual characters in a string to see if it is within the requirement, while also counting the amount of space between the input (for example, if the args input are aaaa gggg cccc tttt acgt accg atgc gcta tccg <= there should be 9 spaces) to make an a 2d array from it. I planned on using a for loop first to work with the isDNASequence method,b ut right now for some reason the charAt method doesn't work and i'm stucked at this part of the code. So any pointers or helps are really appreciated. I'm a really big java noob so pardon me if i ask anything stupid :D

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Hamming {

public static boolean isDNASequence(String s) {
    // create an array of acceptable characters
    char[] acceptableInput = { 'a', 'c', 'g', 't' };
    // render the original string s to lower case into string x
    String x = s.toLowerCase();

    // for loop to check if all the characters are acceptable characters or
    // not
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
        boolean isDNASequence = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < acceptableInput.length; j++) {
            if (x.charAt(i) == acceptableInput[j])
                isDNASequence = true;
        }
        // the output of the boolean
        if (isDNASequence == false)
            return false;
    }
    return true;

}

public static int[][] getDistances(String[] sequences) {
    // filter out the data and get the number of strings left
    List<String> validStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int x = 0; x < sequences.length; x++) {
        if (isDNASequence(sequences[x])) {
            validStrings.add(sequences[x]);
        }
    }

    // create the 2D array
    int size = validStrings.size();
    int[][] result = new int[size][];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        result[i] = new int[size];
    }

    // putting the values from getHammingDistance method into the array cell
    for (int z = 0; z < result.length; z++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < result[0].length; j++) {
            result[z][j] = getHammingDistance(sequences[z], sequences[j]);

        }

    }

    return result;

}

public static int getHammingDistance(String sequence1, String sequence2) {
    // Initialise int a, which will be the Hamming distance
    int a = 0;
    /**
     * renders the two strings sequence1 and sequence2 into lower case to
     * make it easier to calculate
     */
    String sequenceX = sequence1.toLowerCase();
    String sequenceY = sequence2.toLowerCase();

    /**
     * I use the for-loop to calculate the Hamming distance based on
     * comparing individual characters of the two strings
     */
    for (int x = 0; x < sequenceX.length(); x++) {
        if (sequenceX.charAt(x) != sequenceY.charAt(x)) {
            a += 1;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

/**
 * Main method
 * 
 * 1. Go through the parameters 2. Ensure they are valid DNA sequences 3.
 * Get the Hamming distance matrix 4. Print out the highest distance only
 * 
 * @param args
 *            - program arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int d = 0;
    for (int q = 0; q < args.length; q++) {
        isDNASequence(args.charAt[q]);
    } if (args.charAt[q] == " "){
        d+=1;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: `args.charAt[q] == " "` should be `args.charAt[q] == ' '`, since `" "` is the empty **String** while `' '` is the empty **char** (And `charAt` returns a `char`).

Comment: @MarounMaroun not sure, but I think you are wrong `' '===" "` is *true*.

Comment: what exactly you need? I dont get it

Comment: I think this is more efficient:
`public static boolean isDNASequence(String s) { return s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[atgc]","").equals(""); }`

Comment: @T.S. nice idea, but if every cod needs to be four char, then this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The `args` in main method is array of String, they are not array of char.
So, the main method should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int d = 0;
    for (int q = 0; q < args.length; q++) {
        isDNASequence(args[q]);
    }
    if (args[q].equals(" ")){
        d+=1;
    }
}
```

If you want code `args[q].equals(" ")` to detect space within arguments, I think you won't need it, since if you run the code from command prompt, space will be seen as argument's separator.
For example, you run this class in command prompt:

```
> java Hamming aaaa gggg cccc tttt acgt accg atgc gcta tccg
```

Then, the `args` value in main method would be `{"aaaa","gggg","cccc","tttt","acgt","accg","atgc","gcta","tccg"}`

Answer (score 0):

`charAt` is a method, and args is a String[] so it should be used `args[0].charAt(q)`.

Personally I would do something like that.

```
String arr = args[0].split(" "); //I wouldnt bother with spaces
```

Then I would do the following;

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].length() != 4) //I m assuming in every 4 char there should be space 
         return false;
    for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length();i++)
         return isDNAsequence(arr[i].charAt(j));
}
```

Also change `isDNASequence(String str)` to `isDNASequence(char c)`